# blank properties on visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Apparently after installing the WP7 development tools for WP7.1, VS 2010 broke in a very strange way, the properties tab is blank when I select a reference, in all other cases it is apparently working. I'm not sure it is the WP7.1 tools setup, but is the single thing happened to my installation in these days. Anyone had the same problem? Fixes?

**Unfortunately uninstall/update does not work!**

Comment: Similar blank proerties can happen if you uninstall the required verison of .NET framework.  Re-installing it fixes that problem, not sure if it applies to yours

Comment: @Attila thanks, the framework are still there. I'm trying to repair vs 2010 setup, will see.

Comment: Full repair doesn't help. try re-install.