# Setup project has empty properties window

Tags: visual-studio-2010, properties, setup-project

Hi I am using visual studio 2010 and I have a setup project.
The properties window of this project is empty and I need it!
I tried everything and it still doesn't show up.
NOTE: I can see the window, but it's empty.
Thanks a lot!

[image]

Comment: you can post a screenshot, it might help.

Comment: the properties window is context based so it shows the properties of the thing you have marked (for instance in the solution view). What do you have selected in your project when you look at the properties window?

Comment: Thanks you for your help. I know I have to mark it.. and i even press F4 which shows the properties window of the file you marked... I see the window, but its empty.

Comment: I can't post  a screen shot... I need 10 reputations or something.

Comment: I think there is a similar [question][1], this may help you.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10723209/blank-properties-on-visual-studio-2010

Comment: @user2080174 - Add the screenshot to an image sharing site and post the link. We can't help you without understanding what the problem is...

Comment: Here is the link http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=34g7nsy&s=7 . I went to user1671639's link and it;s the same problem with no solution. I did a full repair to the vs 2010 and it still exsist.

Comment: I have the same problem on my desktop pc (win7): I see just an empty properties window. The same deployment project on my laptop (Win XP) is shown correctly. Has anybody a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Initially closing all windows get the properties showing again.

Then I noticed clicking on controls didn't change the properties, although  selecting the Properties dropdownlist to change control worked.

Rebooting the (remote) Windows 7 PC resolved the problem for me.

Other things to try include: deleting the suo file, a project clean, resetting VS.